# Why when i load this page , it's will auto call function?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

Why when i load this page , it's will auto call function ?

my main ides is , when i press button it's will display `LOADING` for 2 sec and then start post to `data.php`

but when i test it's , when i load page , i not press button , it's will auto call function `doajax_products_check` How can i apply code to main idea?

index.php

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form name="form1" id="form1id" method="post">
<input type="text" name="products_id" value="1294759">
<input type="text" name="products_color" value="red">
<input type="text" name="products_type" value="electronic">
<input type="button" value="Check" onclick="doajax_products_check()"/>
</form>
<span id="loading" style="display: none;">LOADING</span>
<p id="myplace_data"></p>
<script>
timer = setTimeout
    (
        function doajax_products_check()
            {
                $('#myplace_data').hide();
                $("#loading").fadeIn("slow");
                $.ajax
                    (
                        {
                            url: 'data.php',
                            type: 'POST',
                            data: $('#form1id').serialize(),
                            cache: false,
                            success: function(data)
                                {
                                    $("#loading").fadeOut("slow");
                                    $('#myplace_data').show();
                                    $('#myplace_data').html(data);
                                }
                        }
                    );
            }, 2000
    );
</script>
```

data.php

```
<?PHP echo "completed"; ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should do this:

```
function doajax_products_check() {
    setTimeout(function(){
        $('#myplace_data').hide();
        $("#loading").fadeIn("slow");
        $.ajax
        (
            {
                url: 'data.php',
                type: 'POST',
                data: $('#form1id').serialize(),
                cache: false,
                success: function (data) {
                    $("#loading").fadeOut("slow");
                    $('#myplace_data').show();
                    $('#myplace_data').html(data);
                }
            }
        )
    }, 2000);
}
```

this is append because the setTimeout called the doajax_products_check() function...

Answer (score 0):

`setTimout(callback, delay)` will call the callback function provided after `delay` ms, in your case 2 seconds after you load the page.

Try this instead:

```
<script>
function doajax_products_check(){

    $('#myplace_data').hide();
    $("#loading").fadeIn("slow");    //show loading before waiting for timeout

    setTimeout(function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'data.php',
            type: 'POST',
            data: $('#form1id').serialize(),
            cache: false,
            success: function (data) {
                $("#loading").fadeOut("slow");
                $('#myplace_data').show();
                $('#myplace_data').html(data);
            }
        });
    }, 2000);
}
</script>
```

Check it out here: http://jsfiddle.net/o5vrbqjy/1/

Answer (score 0):

Your script snippet is directly parsed after loading the page and therefore the timeout is set immediately. The timeout has to be set in the onclick-callback.
You can achieved your desired behavior with

```
<script>
function doajax_products_check() {
  setTimeout(function(){
    // Your logic for the check goes here
  }, 2000);
}
</script>
```